# Windows Phone 8 emulator on system that lacks SLAT

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I was about to install Windows 8 Pro on a laptop which supports virtualization but lacks SLAT (SU9400). I wanted to use it as a second dev machine.

It won't work out though because Hyper-V (required by the emulator) would be unavailable due to the lack of SLAT support.

I read that [Windows Server 2012's flavor of Hyper-V doesn't require SLAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/uk_faculty_connection/hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts).

Since the WP8 emulator runs on Hyper-V, does that mean it will work on a SLAT-less system running Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V and the WP8 emulator work fine on such hardware when using Server 2012.

Tested on a machine with VT-x support but lacking VT-x with Extended Page Tables (SLAT).

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're using Windows Server 2012, you should have no
problems running Hyper-V with the WP8 Emulator without having to worry
about SLAT. Most systems running x86 virtualization like VT-x should be
able to handle WP8 just fine as long as you're on a newer system so as to
ensure the processing power to handle the tasks you're looking to run.
Even when WP8 runs, it can run rather slowly on older compatible systems.

Comment: I have noticed it is terribly slow to deploy the app into the emulator (perhaps minutes, versus seconds on my desktop). Once loaded though the program itself runs fine.

Comment: I've done the same on a Windows Server 2012 VM. 5 minutes to launch an app. But Hyper-V virtual network adapters were configured in a better way under WS2012 than under Windows 8, so Internet was working OOTB in the emulator. Plus, no need for SLAT. I'm on an AMD A6, so I confirm.

Comment: Just checked again, and apps are deploying automatically. It's the emulator itself that takes between 4:30 and 5 minutes to load.